# Javascript sudoku code hangs sometimes

Tags: javascript, freeze, sudoku

I have a feeling that I'm in over my head. I'm trying to write a javascript sudoku game. Instead of posting all of my code, here's a [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15297689/sudoku/sudoku.html) to my game. My source is [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15297689/sudoku/sudoku.js) Right now, it just (attempts to) spits out the solution grid. My problem is, the code will hang indefinitely sometimes. Other times it will successfully create a grid in under a second in Firefox. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I posted a link to my code in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're just randomly placing numbers, it's possible for your puzzle to get into a state where *no* new number can satisfy what you've already got. For example:

```
123|   |
456|   |
78 |9  |
---+---+---
   |   |
   |   |
   |   |
---+---+---
   |   |
   |   |
   |   |
```

You will probably need to add backtracking so your algorithm can reverse changes it's made when you detect this kind of situation.

Comment: I have backtracking. When no solution is available, the code will reset the row. I think that's where my problem lies. I just can't figure it out.

Comment: You might have to backtrack more than just the current row, though.

Comment: Again, you might need to go back more than one row. You should probably try to implement a proper backtracking algorithm using a stack, rather than simply going back and trying more random numbers.

Comment: I must not understand the concept of a backtracking algorithm. What do you mean by a stack?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking has a good explanation and examples. An important characteristic is that there is no randomness involved.